# Does SQLAlchemy support Pervasive PSQL? connection string for it?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I googled and found this [sqlalchemy-pervasive dialect](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-pervasive/). I pipped it, but I have no idea how to use it.

What is connection string to pass to **create_engine(.....)** for sqlalchemy to connect to pervasive psql? is there any other third party driver or dialect?

Comment: It looks to me as if `pervasive://...` ought to work.

Answer (score 2):

After I did a:

```
pip install sqlalchemy-pervasive
```

This worked for me:

```
server='localhost'
database='TEST6'
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(f'DRIVER=Pervasive ODBC Interface;SERVERNAME={server};DBQ={database}')
engine = create_engine("pervasive:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(f'DRIVER=Pervasive ODBC Interface;SERVERNAME={server}:{port};DBQ={database}')
engine = sa.create_engine("pervasive:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

con = engine.connect()
query = 'SELECT * FROM Clientes'
con.execute(query)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Im getting a error using this format. Im getting this message "sqlalchey.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: not an executable object: "select * from TABLE" I am using the same code that you posted above. Did you face this issue at all?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add text from SQL alchemy. "from sqlalchemy import text" then query = (text("select *from SQL"))